# Prove that the set of maximizers are independent of parameter in the objective function

Tags: optimization, variational-calculus

A maximization problem reads as
$$ J(y) = \sum_{k=1}^{K} \sigma_k(y)^q \mathop{\rightarrow}^{y} max$$
where $q \in [1,\infty]$ is a user-defined parameter and functions $\sigma_k, k=\{1,\dots,K\}$ satisfy these two conditions for any given $y$:
$$ \sigma_1(y) \geq \sigma_2(y) \geq \dots \geq \sigma_K(y) \geq 0.$$

and

$$\sum_{k=1}^{K} \sigma_{k}(y) = K$$

I would like to prove that the set of maximizers for $J(y)$ is independent of the choice of $q$.

Comment: When you write $\sigma_k^q(y)$, do you mean exponentiation by $q$? It would probably be easier to understand if you wrote $\sigma_k(y)^q$ in that case.

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth thanks for the comments. Changes are done. I also realized that there is something fishy in my attempt at the question.

Comment: In (2), I don't think there should be a $K$ factor on the left.

Comment: I don't think you proved that $y$ at the maximum point of $J$ is independent from $q$. You just found an upper bound probably for $\sigma_{k}$.

Comment: @AloneProgrammer, you are right. I observed later that my attempt does not say anything about the minimizers.

Comment: I've given this occasional thought over the past couple of days. I don't think that the statement is actually true, but also can't come up with an obvious counter example. The statement is clearly predicated on (i) the positivity and (ii) ordering of the functions given in the second formula. The *actual* ordering doesn't matter, of course, since we're summing things. But the statement implies that the functions don't cross each other, and that is a barrier I can't seem to overcome when constructing counter examples. Regardless, I'm convinced that the statement is not true.

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth Thanks for looking into it. I am sorry that I did not mention one constraint that is applicable to my problem, i.e., a sum of $\sigma_k$ is always a constant and it is equal to the K irrespective of the value of $y$. I thought initially, it is not important. Sorry for that. The statement mentioned in the quastion are mainly based on the numerical observations.

Comment: Well, but then *any* $y$ maximizes the objective function for $q=1$. That will clearly not be the case for other $q$.

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth What if OP excludes $q=1$ and say $q > 1$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following up on my comment on the original question, I have finally managed to construct a counter example that shows that the statement is not in fact correct. Define the positive part of a function,
$$
  [x]^+ = \begin{cases}x & \text{if $x\ge 0$} \\ 0 & \text{otherwise.}\end{cases}
$$
The let
$$
  \sigma_1(y) = 1+ \left[\tfrac 14 - |y-1|\right]^+
$$
and
$$
  \sigma_2(y) = \left[\tfrac 12 - |y|\right]^+.
$$
These are both non-negative functions with the requested ordering. They look like this:
[image]
The point is that the bump of $\sigma_2$ is larger than the bump of $\sigma_1$, and consequently the maximum of their sum is at $y=0$. But $\sigma_1\ge 1$, and so if you take a positive power of it, its bump gets larger; on the other hand, $\sigma_2<1$ and so its bump gets smaller if you take some power of it. Indeed, 
plotting both $\sigma_1(y)+\sigma_2(y)$ and $\sigma_1(y)^4+\sigma_2(y)^4$ shows how this works:
[image]
In other words, for $q=1$ the maximum is at $y=0$, whereas for $q=4$, it is at $y=1$. This contradicts your claimed independence of the location of the maximizer.

Comment: OP added another condition in comments as: $$\sum_{k=1}^{K} \sigma_{k}(y) = K$$ for any value of $y$. In your counter example case: $K=2$, obviously: $\sum_{k=1}^{K} \sigma_{k}(y) \neq K$.

Comment: Uh, that doesn't make any sense. If $\sum_k \sigma_k(y)=K$, then *any* $y$ is a maximizer -- the objective function is simply constant.

Comment: You mean $J(y)$ would be constant? I don't think so...

Comment: But for $q=1$ it is!

Comment: Yes, I know but I'm interested to see if it is possible to create counter example for $q > 1$ or not.

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth After a few more numerical experiments, I realized that my statement may not be true in general. Sorry for wasting your time. I am not sure whether I should delete the question or not. What do you recommend?

Comment: No, it's still a valid question. It just doesn't have the answer you were looking for :-)